# getting well formed output from ant - sshexec in groovy script

Tags: ant, groovy, ssh

my problem is, that the output from the ant task alwas has some [ssh-exec] infotext at the beginning. can i suppress / disable that?

my code so far:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()

// .... variable definition ...

ant.sshexec(host: host,
            port: port,
            trust: true,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            command: 'ls')

>>> output:

  [sshexec] Connecting to foomachine.local:22
  [sshexec] cmd : ls
  [sshexec] oldarchive.gz
  [sshexec] newarchive.gz
  [sshexec] empty-db.sh
  [sshexec] testfile.py
```

i just want to have the raw output from the cmd i execute...

some ideas?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can save the raw output inside an Ant property:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.sshexec(host: host,
            port: port,
            trust: true,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            command: 'ls',
            outputproperty: 'result')

def result = ant.project.properties.'result'
```

Comment: if it's exactly what you wanted, I suggest you accept the answer! :)

Comment: Not sure why, but my outputproperty stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that outputproperty is not working properly (it does not set the ant variable).

I often use trycatch from antcontrib to test if error occurs instead of reading return value.

Example :

```
<trycatch>
<try>
      <sshexec host="@{host}" failonerror="true" username="${username}" password="${password}" timeout="${ssh.timeout}" command="@{command}" usepty="@{usepty}" trust="true" />
</try>
<catch>
      <echo>Service already stopped!</echo>
</catch>
</trycatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tripped over the same issue in gradle and from there I had to change the way to access the property:
According to [the official gradle doc 3.3](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/ant.html#sec:ant_properties)

```
println ant.antProp
println ant.properties.antProp
println ant.properties['antProp']
```

is the correct way to go.

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.sshexec(host: host,
            port: port,
            trust: true,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            command: 'ls',
            outputproperty: 'result')

def result = ant.properties.'result'
```

Hope this helps people in the same situation. Cheers