# How to list a directory using ANT's SCP task over SFTP?

Tags: ant, groovy, sftp

The [FTP task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html) in ant allows you to list a given directory using syntax as follows:

```
  <ftp action="list"
       server="ftp.apache.org"
       userid="admin"
       password="${password}"
       listing="c:\\temp\\listing-temp.txt">
    <fileset>
      <include name="response/*.zip"/>
    </fileset>
  </ftp>
```

**The Groovy Syntax is:**

```
ant.ftp(
        action:"list",
        server:"ftp.apache.org",
        userid:"admin",
        password:"$password",
        verbose:false,
        listing:"c:\\temp\\listing-temp.txt"){
            fileset(dir:"") { include(name:"response/*.zip") }
        }
```

The [SCP Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) is primarly used when needing to work over the SFTP protocol.  However, I don't see any mechanism to list over SFTP using the SCP task.  Is there a known technique to perform a listing using the scp task? The only alternative I have right now is to pull the files down as a 'listing'.  I would really like to just list the contents and avoid the overhead of pulling the files down.

```
ant.scp(
            file: "aUserID@sftp.apache.org:$path/*.zip",
            toDir: "C:\\dev\\tmp",
            password: "$password",
            trust: 'true',
            verbose: "false",
            sftp: "true")
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121637/getting-well-formed-output-from-ant-sshexec-in-groovy-script

Comment: @martinclayton Should sshexec work for the server that has only been previously accessed using SFTP?  I'm getting "Remote command failed with exit status 255" when using sshexec but scp does work.

Comment: scp means "copy over ssh", so it provides only "copy" functions.